# Unable to get card details for connected account in Stripe

Tags: api, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am trying to  retrieve card details for connected accounts customer, As per stripe  documentation we need to pass stripe_account parameter in each api call to work with connected accounts. However in case of retrieving card details it is throwing error for the stripe_account parameter. 
Following is how my api call looks like:

```
\Stripe\Customer::retrieveSource(
  'cus_GqzjjKIQXO1JgB',
  'card_1GJHkSEyjL72dRjPECxaHlEF',["stripe_account" =>'xxxxxxxxx']
);
```

Following is the error:

`Received unknown parameter: stripe_account`

Can  someone please help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of the signature of the retrieveSource method:

`public static function retrieveSource($id, $sourceId, $params = null, $opts = null)`

In this case the `stripe_account` is being passed as a param instead of an opt.

You can fix this by passing an empty array for params:

```
<?php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxx');

$ss = \Stripe\Customer::retrieveSource(
  'cus_xxx',
  'card_xxx',
  [],
  ["stripe_account" => 'acct_xxx']
);
?>
```

Hope that helps!

v3nkman